# Как преобразовать число в дату в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, datetime, timedelta

У меня есть excel файл со столбцом даты в виде общего формата

[image: общий формат]

Как я могу изменить столбец в pandas из общего формата в формат даты как это делает эксель? Pandas воспринимает его как число

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столбец, который я хочу получить

[image: формат даты]

Я знаю, что возможно проще изменить это в экселе, а потом читать файл, но я бы хотела автоматизировать эту работу, так как данные приходят каждый день в таком формате

Comment: как на счёт https://github.com/bradbase/xlcalculator

Comment: На будущее - приводите пример данных и желаемого результата в вопросе в *воспроизводимом виде*, то есть текстом.

Comment: вопрос очень интересный, кстати. здесь действительно разница в два дня, но, если сделать =РАЗНДАТ() (=DATEDIF) в самом экселе, то получается разность дат в 1 день.  странные дела. я верю, что python считает честно. а что творится в голове экселя - не известно.

Answer (score 2):

Excel хранит дату и время в виде вещественного числа. Целая часть этого числа - количество дней с полуночи 1 января 1900. Дробная - время.

можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([40557, 44664, 55603])
```

df:

```
       0
0  44655
1  44664
2  55603
```

дальше преобразовываем:

```
df["date"] = (pd.to_datetime("1900-01-01")+pd.to_timedelta(df[0], unit="D"))
```

**UPDATE:**

как выяснилось, excel получил по наследству [баг](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev), из-за чего вычисления разницы дат в Excel и python/pandas отличаются на 2 дня.
поэтому правильно вычислять будет так:

```
df["date"] = (pd.to_datetime("1899-12-30 00:00:00", yearfirst=True)+pd.to_timedelta(df[0], unit="D"))
```

теперь df:

```
       0       date
0  40557 2011-01-14
1  44664 2022-04-13
2  55603 2052-03-25
```

вы получаете дату типа `datetime`

Comment: спасибо! но почему-то на два дня позже показывает

Comment: @Valerie вопрос очень интересный, кстати. здесь действительно разница в два дня, но, если сделать =РАЗНДАТ() (=DATEDIF) в самом экселе, то получается разность дат в 1 день. странные дела. я верю, что python считает честно. а что творится в голове экселя - не известно.

Comment: @Valerie преступление раскрыто: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev

Answer (score 1):

еще как вариант (пример данных позаимствовал из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1424367/457260) @strawdog, спасибо ему):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[0]-25567, unit='D')  # 25567 - разница между Excel и unix (1900-01-01 и 1970-01-01)

>>> df
'''
       0       date
0  40557 2011-01-16
1  44664 2022-04-15
2  55603 2052-03-27
```